# Change position of range bar in html5

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div with a range bar to set a value, the user has also two predifined choice for this value. When he chooses one of the predifined choice I would like the position of the bar to adapt, but it doesn't work.

```
<div id="temp_DB" class="dialogTable" style="display: none;">
input id="tempOpt1"  class="tableButton" type="radio" name="tempopt" onclick='setandshowValue(0)'/>
<label for="tempOpt1" ><span id="labelRect">ZPE (0 K)</span></label>
 <input id="tempOpt2"  class="tableButton" type="radio" name="tempopt" onclick='setandshowValue(298)'/>
<label for="tempOpt2" ><span id="labelRect">RT (298 K)</span></label>
<input id="tempOpt3"  value="0" type="range" name="tempopt" min="0" max="500" onchange="showValue(this.value)"/>
<span id="range" style="font-size: 20px; float: left;">298</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showValue(newValue)
{
        document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=newValue;
}
function setandshowValue(newValue)
{
var text='"'+newValue+'"';
        document.getElementById("tempOpt3").value=text;
        document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=newValue;
}
</script>
</div>
```

In the script part, in setandshowValue function, if I set there text="100", it works, the range bar adapt but I am not managing to do it with the value in the argument. Does anyone know why and how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: You have a typo, your first input miss his `<`.

Comment: Looks good to me after fixing the typo and ditching the display: none

Comment: The typo appeared when I copy paste the code thus it's not that. But it is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don think you need to Add the speech marks just set the range value to what's inputted and it should work.

document.getElementById("tempOpt3").value=newValue;
 document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=newValue;

Comment: Yeah, I tested and this works : `document.getElementById("tempOpt3").value=newValue;`

Comment: That was my first try and it didn't work. I don't understand why it works for others and not for me....

Comment: Ok sorry guys, it was a typo but someplace else, I wrote newValue instead of newvalue!